# looping batch action using ping

Tags: loops, batch-file, ping

I'm trying to loop an action every 10 minutes using ping, although I understand the ping principal I don't know how to loop an action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on DOS/Windows, you can add a label to a batch file like this:

```
:l
```

and then later on you can goto it:

```
goto l
```

Comment: @echo off 

:LOOPME
Sleep 5

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set pas= 
set s=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 
for /l %%a in (1,1,6) do ( 
   set /a n=!random! %% 62 
   call set pas=!pas!%%s:~!n!,1%%) 

ren %0 %pas%.bat

GOTO LOOPME

Comment: cant get the above to loop though (sorry cant see where the section to add code in comments is)

Comment: well when i click my bat it dosnt keep on renaming it ill just test it again

Comment: @Meldrum: You can't seriously expect the self-renaming batch file to go on running after the renaming, can you? I ran your script, the file renamed itself, then the batch terminated. And that's quite natural, because the system attempts to load and run the next line from the *original* batch file. After the file renamed itself, the system lost it.

Comment: The code also should terminate after 32 iterations due to the maximum depth of local environments (you're missing an `endlocal` somewhere).